# how i can publish without destination url?

Tags: .net, iis, .net-6.0, publish, visual-studio-2022

I don't have a link in the "Associations" section.

How can I publish a project without him?

IIS

[image]

VS 2022

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Destination URL setting isn't required. When Visual Studio finishes deploying the application, it automatically opens your default browser to this URL. If you don't want the browser to open automatically after deployment, leave this box blank.